# How do I "connect" my view models with my views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I would like to know how I can set a ViewModel in WPF for UserControls.

The project is set up as follows:-

MainWindow with its associated MainViewModel which I instantiate and access using DataContext

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

This MainWindow has the user control set as

`<local:UC x:Name="Sample Control"/>`

- In my MainViewModel class, I have an instance of the UCViewModel class I would like to use as a view model for this user control and perform Binding with the sub-elements in this user control.

What would be the best way to do this? I have searched on Google for this but I am not able to find a clear answer. Let me know if more detail is required. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should not have an instance of UCViewModel in your MainViewModel.

Comment: @Lucas of course that is completely untrue.

Comment: It depends of the the 'pattern'. Maybe Lucas uses ViewModel-First pattern using ContentControl+DataTemplate. Then it would be `<ContentControl  Content="{Binding UCViewModelInstanceProp}" />` and `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:UCViewModel }">
                <local:UC />
            </DataTemplate>`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `MainViewModel` has its instance of `UCViewModel` exposed as a property, then you can simply bind the user control's data context to that property:

```
<local:UC x:Name="Sample Control" DataContext="{Binding UCViewModelInstanceProp}" />
```